# Deck of cards(Array), getting the value of a dealt hand

Tags: javascript

If I have an Array of cards like:

```
var deck = ["AH", "AS", "AD", "AC", "2H", "2S", "2D", "2C", "3H", "3S", "3D", "3C", "4H", "4S", "4D", "4C", "5H", "5S", "5D", "5C", "6H", "6S", "6D", "6C", "7H", "7S", "7D", "7C", "8H", "8S", "8D", "8C", "9H", "9S", "9D", "9C", "10H", "10S", "10D", "10C", "JH", "JS", "JD", "JC", "QH", "QS", "QD", "QC", "KH", "KS", "KD", "KC"];
```

And deal 2 of those to the user:

```
var userHand = deck.splice([Math.floor(Math.random()*deck.length)+1], 1);
userHand.push(deck.splice([Math.floor(Math.random()*deck.length)+1], 1).join(""))
```

I get something like:

```
["5S", "2H"];
```

And those 2 cards are off the deck.

So far so good, but now I'd want to count the points that the user has, in this case it would be 7. I need a way to assign values to figure cards and Aces.
I've created a function but it's wrong somewhere, I keep getting 2:

```
function countPoints (){

  for ( let i = 0; i < userHand.length; i++){

  if ( userHand[i] == "AH" || "AS" || "AD" || "AC") {
     userPoints += 1;
  } else if ( userHand[i] == "2H" || "2S" || "2D" || "2C") {
     userPoints += 2;
  } else if ( userHand[i] == "3H" || "3S" || "3D" || "3C") {
     userPoints += 3;
  }  else if ( userHand[i] == "4H" || "4S" || "4D" || "4C") {
     userPoints += 4;
  } else if ( userHand[i] == "5H" || "5S" || "5D" || "5C") {
     userPoints += 5;
  } else if ( userHand[i] == "6H" || "6S" || "6D" || "6C") {
     userPoints += 6;
  } else if ( userHand[i] == "7H" || "7S" || "7D" || "7C") {
     userPoints += 7;
  } else if ( userHand[i] == "8H" || "8S" || "8D" || "8C") {
     userPoints += 8;
  } else if ( userHand[i] == "9H" || "9S" || "9D" || "9C") {
     userPoints += 9;
  } else if ( userHand[i] == "10H" || "10S" || "10D" || "10C") {
     userPoints += 10;
  } else if ( userHand[i] == "JH" || "JS" || "JD" || "JC") {
     userPoints += 10;
  } else if ( userHand[i] == "QH" || "QS" || "QD" || "QC") {
     userPoints += 10;
  } else if ( userHand[i] == "KH" || "KS" || "KD" || "KC") {
     userPoints += 10;
  } 
  }
  }
```

Comment: how about instead of having a list strings as a deck - have a list of objects, each object would have two properties: name and points

Comment: As pointed out by other users, the problem is the syntax for the OR conditions. However, if you are sure that all strings are well-formed, you can get rid of that huge block of code and replace it with `userPoints += parseInt(userHand[i]) || userHand[i][0] == 'A' && 1 || 10;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`userHand[i] == "AH" || "AS" || "AD" || "AC"` results in a truthy value. You need to use check the equality for each card suit, not just OR them together.

```
userHand[i] == "AH" || userHand[i] == "AS" || 
userHand[i] == "AD" || userHand[i] == "AC"
```

Theres quite a bit of room for improvement here to keep things dry as well, but this solves your root problem. Feel free to ask on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: That does work and you are right, it could be prettier. Thank you. Accepting when it allows me.